# https check on server

Tags: tomcat, https

I have a tomcat server deployed on azure which has my REST API. Till now, I used HTTP to contact the server from my android app and get responses. Today, I added a self signed certificate to the server and when I tested using the android app (by changing the URL to https) everything was working fine. But, I want to confirm if the responses are actually being encrypted. How do I check this?

Comment: Hello - I'm trying to do the same thing but was wondering how you managed to add the self-signed cert to the server? Did you use an embedded tomcat with the cert inside and upload it to azure or did you just use their external tomcat server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Command**

```
curl -k -v https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed
```

**Output**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.30.252.129...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.129) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: github.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> GET /corvusoft/restbed HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: github.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server GitHub.com is not blacklisted
< Server: GitHub.com
...
```

Curl documentation can be found [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

```
-k, --insecure

(SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used.


-v, --verbose

Be more verbose/talkative during the operation. Useful for debugging and seeing what's going on "under the hood". A line starting with '>' means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by curl that is hidden in normal cases, and a line starting with '*' means additional info provided by curl.
```

Comment: This works fine. But, when I run tcpdump on the server and capture the packets when I call the API from the app, I don't see any TLS packets in it.

Comment: @Meher So you have your answer then.

Comment: @Meher This maybe of some use: http://packetpushers.net/using-ssldump-decode-ssltls-packets/