# HTTPS ACTIVATED FOR WEB SITE

Tags: https

I need to confirm that my web application connection to JBOSS6 server is done via HTTPS only.

What are some technical checks that I can make ?

This link was useful to me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088242/https-check-on-server)

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completing the configuration changes for JBOSS, you must restart JBoss Web as you normally do. You should be able to access any web application supported by JBoss Web via SSL. For example, try:

```
https://yourdomain:8443
```

It should land you to your start page.

If you want more info, please comment. :)

Comment: Is it enough check to confirm that all other URLs in my web application are in secure mode?

Comment: Yes it will be enough